# iOS: Inheritance with different xib files

Tags: ios, swift, xib, iboutlet

UIViewA is defined in .xib and .swift.
I would like to create a UIView with it own .xib that inherits from UIViewA with several extra properties.

So:

```
class UIViewA: UIView {
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var subtitleLabel: UILabel!
}

class UIViewB: UIViewA {
    @IBOutlet weak var thirdLabel: UILabel!
}
```

Both UIViewA and UIViewB have titleLabel and subtitleLabel. They are just positioned differently in there xibs. Is there a way I could drag titleLabel in UIVIewB.xib to the titleLabel IBOutlet in UIViewA.swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it. In your example, if you open `UIVIewB.xib` and the file owner is the class `UIVIewB` you can open another editor window with the class `UIViewA` and you can drag the UI elements to the UIViewA properties.

Like this: [image]